# Pass ArrayList<ZipEntry> from one activity to another

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

So for one of my personal projects I want to pass an arraylist of ZipEntry objects from one activity to another but I am unable to do so. I have tried the following things:

1. Creating Bundle() and passing that bundle using putExtra()
2. Passing ArrayList directly using putExta()

**Creating bundle & passing it using putExtra():**
Implementation:

```
// Add data to intent and launch install activity
val newActIntent = Intent(this, InstallActivity::class.java)
val data = Bundle()
data.putSerializable("x", languageListAdapter.selectedItems)
newActIntent.putExtra("z", data)
this.startActivity(newActIntent)
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parcel: unknown type for value split_config.en.apk
```

**Passing ArrayList<> directly using putExtra()**
Implementation:

```
val newActIntent = Intent(this, InstallActivity::class.java)
newActIntent.putExtra("x", languageListAdapter.selectedItems)
this.startActivity(newActIntent)
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parcel: unknown type for value split_config.en.apk
```

*Note: ZipEntry object is java.util.zip.ZipEntry*

Comment: Is your ZipEntry object serializable? (implements the Serializable interface).

Comment: Updated question to explain what is ZipEntry

Comment: The in that case you can use a singleton object to hold the selected ZipFile list. The easiest method is to use the Application class.

Comment: Thanks a lot I was able to fix this by creating a singleton object.

Answer (score 0):

In order to send an `ArrayList<ZipEntry>` from one `Activity` to another you need to make sure that your `ZipEntry` object is serializable, you can do it by implementing `Serializable` interface.
You can also use `Parcelable` as an alternative of `Serializable`.

If you use `Serializable` you use `getSerializableExtra` and if it's `Parcelable` you use `getParcelableArrayListExtra`

```
@Parcelize
data class ZipEntry : Parcelable
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how this would work as I am using java.util.zip.ZipEntry

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue thanks to the comment from @wambada

**Implementation:**

1. Created a singleton object to store the ArrayLists

```
object ZipEntrySingleton {
    var aList: ArrayList<ZipEntry>? = null
    var lList: ArrayList<ZipEntry>? = null
}
```

2. Created the singleton object in activity 1 and passed the data to it.

```
// Add data to intent and launch install activity
val newActIntent = Intent(this, InstallActivity::class.java)
val x = ZipEntrySingleton
x.aList = xListAdapter.selectedItems
x.lList = yListAdapter.selectedItems
this.startActivity(newActIntent)
```

3. Retrieved the data in the new activity by using:

```
ZipEntrySingleton.aList
```

Comment: Just remember to dispose tthe singleton when you are done with it.